# How do I set up Postfix *_restrictions configuration parameters safely with whitelists and blacklists?

Tags: postfix, configuration

### Learning and Trying to Understand

I've spent the last week learning about what Postfix can do to help reduce spam. If I understand correctly the different `*_restrictions` configuration parameters control *when* the checks are done and then the list of restrictions such as `permit_mynetworks` and `check_client_access` control *what* is checked. Is that correct?

If I understand correctly, the checks are performed in the following order:

- smtpd_client_restrictions
- smtpd_helo_restrictions
- smtpd_sender_restrictions
- smtpd_relay_restrictions
- smtpd_recipient_restrictions

Is that correct? And if I understand correctly, `smtpd_delay_reject` does not affect the order of the checks but only affects *when* the reject is *sent*. Right?

### My Sever Set Up

The `smtpd_relay_restrictions` configuration parameter doesn't seem to be set on my Plesk 11 server. My Postfix version is 2.8.4.

I've also noticed that some of the checks are listed multiple times under different configuration parameters. Do they need to be listed multiple times?

Here's my current configuration:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re

smtpd_client_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination
```

If I understand correctly, that would be the same as this:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =

smtpd_client_restrictions =

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
    permit_mynetworks
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination
```

The blacklists file is empty. The the no_auth files has this:

```
/^/ PREPEND X-No-Auth: unauthenticated sender
```

and no_relay file has this:

```
/^/ PREPEND X-No-Relay: not in my network
```

If I understand correctly, the last two add the headers to all emails that are not already permitted.

### Concerns

- **Repeated Checks**
  Does Postfix perform the check again when it's listed multiple times? Or does Postfix know it already did that check? If the checks are performed multiple times, that seems like a waste. If they are not performed multiple times, do the no_auh/no_relay headers actually get added properly in all cases?
- **Missing smtpd_relay_restrictions**
  Excerpt from [Postfix SMTP relay and access control](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html)

  > NOTE: Postfix versions before 2.10 did not have smtpd_relay_restrictions. They combined the mail relay and spam blocking policies, under smtpd_recipient_restrictions. This could lead to unexpected results. For example, a permissive spam blocking policy could unexpectedly result in a permissive mail relay policy.

  Another excerpt:

  > Some people recommend placing ALL the access restrictions in the smtpd_recipient_restrictions list. Unfortunately, this can result in too permissive access.

  So I don't want to list all restrictions under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, but having multiple restrictions and the same checks under different restrictions gets confusing. Is it safe to use just `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and `smtpd_relay_restrictions` and ignore the client, helo, sender?
- **Blacklist**
  Isn't that blacklist rather early in the list? If the sender is part of my network and can authenticate, should I really block based on sender email? Right now the table is empty, but I am not sure what Plesk component might add email addresses to that table. It would also go against the RFC that requires 100% delivery to postmaster@ and abuse@ addresses.

### Here's What I Want to Accomplish

- keep it fairly simple
- ensure I don't create an open relay or other security hole
- ensure I don't block valid email
- whitelist postmaster@ and abuse@ addresses that exist in the virtual alias table
- blacklist IP address blocks of spammers from China/Korea
- reject, with regular expression, all but certain recipient addresses on a domain that uses a catch-all. I'm using a catch-all on one domain so I can use VERP-y bounce addresses even though Plesk doesn't support VERP.

### Here's What I Was Thinking

In /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
#smtpd_client_restrictions =
#smtpd_helo_restrictions =
#smtpd_sender_restrictions =

smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
    reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/custom/recipient_checks.pcre
    check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/custom/sinokorea.cidr
    check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists
```

In /etc/postfix/custom/recipient_checks.pcre

```
# Always accept mail to postmaster@ and abuse@
/^postmaster@/ OK
/^abuse@/ OK

# Reject all mail sent to mailapp.ourdomain.com
# except for certain specific recipients
# and bounce messages which may use VERP
if /@mailapp\.ourdomain\.com$/
!/^(?:validuser|anothervalid|bounces(?:\+.+)?)@/ REJECT
endif
```

I've come across examples that have the `@` escaped in the regular expressions. It's not a special character, is it?

**Would my proposed configuration accomplish want I want?**

(Note to self and any other Plesk users reading this - A cron job may be required to regularly restore the changes to main.cf file since some Plesk actions seem to overwrite this file.)

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is long question. I'll try to answering some part of above question. And maybe draw a summary based on them.

*Disclaimer: I haven't used plesk, but I have used postfix. This question age was more than one year, so maybe the plesk has update  their config for postfix. But I think this question would be useful for someone who design and implement postfix restriction*

#### Q1: Are these two configs equivalent?

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re

smtpd_client_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination
```

AND

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =

smtpd_client_restrictions =

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
    permit_mynetworks
    check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination
```

If an email comes from mynetworks, then it won't be checked by `/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re` and `/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re`. It means that email will be **accepted and not changed**. In terms of postfix action (REJECT, ACCEPT), it won't different, but for plesk maybe these two headers is *important*.

#### Q2: Does Postfix perform the check again when it's listed multiple times? Or does Postfix know it already did that check? If the checks are performed multiple times, that seems like a waste. If they are not performed multiple times, do the no_auh/no_relay headers actually get added properly in all cases?

Yeah, it's maybe looks like wasteful when two checks repeated. But this repeated checks will be placed in different places/restrictions. And in every checks, there are some logic or algorithm how postfix treated an email. You may concern of repeated check if the check was heavy one such as [check_policy_service](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_policy_service) or DNSBL. For lightweight check like [permit_mynetwork](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#permit_mynetworks), you may ignore it.

#### Q3:  Is it safe to use just smtpd_recipient_restrictions and smtpd_relay_restrictions and ignore the client, helo, sender?

Well, with two smtpd_recipient_restrictions and smtpd_relay_restrictions should be enough for some advanced restriction. But it's for postfix >= 2.10. For user with postfix < 2.10, you can places checks in multiple directive so postfix won't [become too permissive.](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#danger)

#### Q4: Would my proposed configuration accomplish want I want?

Yep, good job for simplifying your current postfix restriction. But beware that postfix was part of plesk. The engineer of plesk may arrange those restriction for some reasons such as modularity or simple maintenance.

Summary:

- Placing all restriction in on of smtpd_*_restriction isn't recommended.
- For this reason, you can use smtpd_relay_restriction for postfix >= 2.10 or other restriction check for postfix < 2.10

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, don't leave home without:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
```

These have been catching the majority for me all by themselves.